# How to obtain data from a particular cell

Tags: firebase, react-table

I am trying to create an administrator page using Firebase and React-Table. 
My main issue is that I need to be able to pull the data from a certain cell to then call it in a function.

For example: On one row, you have the user's information (Name - Email).

In the last cell of that row you have a button that says Delete User.

I need to be able to pull the email from the second cell of that row and use it in the function call to delete the user.
Not sure how to obtain the data.

This is the table rendered. The info want is in the second column called email.

````
                    ? <LoadingScreen/>
                    : <ReactTable
                        data={this.state.data
                        ? this.state.data
                        : []}
                        columns={keys.map(string => {
                        return ({Header: string, accessor: string})

                    }).concat([{
                        Header: "Actions",
                        accessor: null,
                        Cell: row => (
                            <div>

                                <Button type='primary' onClick={this.showModal}> Change Password </Button>
                                <Modal
                                    title="Change Password"
                                     visible={this.state.visible}
                                     onOk={this.handleOk}
                                     onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                                     mask= {false}
                                 >
                                <PasswordChangeForm/>
                                </Modal>
                                <Button type='danger' onClick={this.showDeleteConfirm}> Delete User </Button>
                            </div>
                        )
                        }])}
                        defaultPageSize={10}
                        className="-striped -highlight"/>
}  ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get row information from getTrProps property.**

```
 <ReactTable
   getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => ({
              onClick: e => console.log(rowInfo.original)
              })}
 />
```

In the code above when a row is clicked it logs the details of that particular row. You can filter out the information you need and call external functions inside.